# Visual Studio 2013 Install Updates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it important to install the version one and two for visual studio 2013 simultaneous to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to install previous updates. The update packages are cumulative, and include all feature additions and bug fixes from previous versions. You just need to install the latest one.

This is documented in the KB articles describing each update. For example, [Description of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432).

The same is true for the various Visual Studio 2012 updates.

Answer (score 1):

No just install Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013 & you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The Update 1 is more focused on fixing issues with the VS2013:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/01/20/visual-studio-2013-update-1.aspx

Whilst the Update 2, according to VS2013 team, provides more new features:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/04/the-release-candidate-for-visual-studio-2013-update-2.aspx